# HD Video Capture software for Logitech Web Cam?

Tags: video, webcam

I have a Logitech HD C910 webcam for which Logitech has no up-to-date drivers. They stopped updating for Mac at 10.6.

I would just write it off, like so many webcams before it. But it's an AWESOME camera. Its color balance and low-light clarity are just outstanding. It would be a shame to throw away such a great camera. Especially since I have several.

And, while the Logitech software crashes and burns upon launching, other apps can at least partially see the camera. FaceTime and PhotoBooth, for example. They don't have video capture, however. Final Cut Pro, which does have video capture, does *not* see it.

So...looking for recommendations for other applications or utilities I might use to capture video from it. Failing that, looking for replacement recommendations. Not from Logitech, apparently, because they don't seem to support Mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the C910 and it's totally working on my Mac Pro and my MacBook Air.

QuickTime can record 1080p, as well as iMovie/FinalCut should.

There is no necessarity for drivers or additional software to get this working on your Mac.

Comment: And so it does! I never thought of using QuickTime Player to record! Final Cut Pro does not (I'm using the latest version, 10.1.3). But if QTP records, good enough for government work! Thanks.

Comment: Glad I could help. Seems strange to me, that FinalCut is not recording at all. I simpyl record in QucikTime, convert to AppleProRes 422 and then cut it in FinalCut Pro 7..

Comment: FCP X (10) is a very different animal than FCP 7. Entirely.