# Logitech C910 webcam El Capitan compatability?

Tags: video, quicktime, webcam

Are there any drivers available for the Logitech C910 after OS 10.6.x? It works in Logitech Webcam Software, but the camera isn't recognized in any other application that accesses the camera. A [similar question from 2014](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/144974/hd-video-capture-software-for-logitech-web-cam) led me to trying the webcam out in QuickTime; in my case, QuickTime recognizes the C910's microphone as "Unknown USB Audio Device," but doesn't recognize the camera.

I've looked both in the Logitech support site and elsewhere for possible drivers, and haven't found anything, so I'm aware that there may be no solution for this.

Update: restarting the computer did help a late 2015 trash can Mac Pro recognize the camera, but restarting did not work for a late 2011 MBP. Meanwhile, it worked perfectly on a late 2012 MBP without much struggle. All these are running El Capitan.

Comment: When you say you checked "a number of places", was one of those places the Logitech support site?  If so, please edit your question to indicate this otherwise your question risks being closed as off-topic.

Comment: I did check the support site - sorry for forgetting to mention it! Question has been updated.

Comment: it seems that the software doesnt offer the same features as the PC version (there is no motion detection in version 2,2 Build 2.2.13. Does anyone know if there is an update that includes this feature that would work on 10.6.8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Fortunately, there is another
> trick that seems to fix the problem immediately using a command line
> force quit, and does not require a reboot:
>
> - Quit all open apps that may try to use the camera
> - Open Terminal, found in the /Applications/Utilities directory in OS X
> - Enter the following command strings exactly, then hit return:
>
>   ```
>     sudo killall VDCAssistant
>   ```
> - Still at the terminal, issue the following command as well:
>
>   ```
>     sudo killall AppleCameraAssistant
>   ```
> - Relaunch the app that was attempting to use the camera

From a post by Reality_Bath on the forum https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/logitech-c930e-not-working-with-mac.1971498/

Comment: The moment I entered my password for the first command, the troublesome camera lit up. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with a C920, it kinda works but doesn't quite 'fit' into the OS. Logitech didn't seem to offer any support for it at all.

I got round it using an intermediary app called [Webcam Settings](https://itunes.apple.com/app/webcam-settings/id533696630?mt=12) [$7.99/£5.99] which essentially turned it into a useful camera again.